# How to pass ID to default value of another view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of incidents which can have associated jobs. I Have a separate views for incidents and jobs. From the incident index page I have the following link to create a new job for that incident:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create","Create", "Job", new { id = item.IncidentID }, null)
```

which takes the incident ID from that field and loads the Job view. I want to pass the ID as a default value for creating a new job, so the job will be assigned the incident ID.

I made this controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
           return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     var newid = id;


     ViewBag.ActionCode = new SelectList(db.ActionTypes, "ActionCode", "ActionType1");
     ViewBag.IncidentID = new SelectList(db.Incidents, "IncidentID", "DefectFreeText");
     return View();
}
```

How can I assign a default value to the form on the create job view ? I thought something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncidentID, id/newid)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: default value on what ? just the id variable ?

Comment: Yea, so the job created is automatically assigned incident ID based on the one passed from the Create Job link on the Incident field. It's derived from a particular value,     @Html.ActionLink("Create","Create", "Job", new { id = item.IncidentID }, null)   which exists for each field in the incidents view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to set a default item for your Incidents dropdown list when user pass that to your create  action method as a querystring. I would avoid using ViewBag approach to transfer your dropdown list data to the view and switch to a strongly typed viewmodel approach.

First create a viewmodel for our create view.

```
public class CreateJobVM
{
  public int IncidentID { set;get;}
  public int ActionTypeID { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> ActionTypes { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Incidents{ set;get;} 
  public CreateJobVM()
  {
    ActionTypes =new List<SelectListItem>();
    Incidents=new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
}
```

And in your GET view,

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
  var vm=new CreateJobVM();
  vm.ActionTypes=GetActionTypes();
  vm.Incidents=GetIncidents();
  if(id.HasValue)
  {
     //set the selected item here
     vm.IncidentID =id.Value;
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetActionTypes` and `GetIncidents` method returns a list of `SelectListItems`, From a DB table/ XML /whatever place you have data

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetActionTypes()
{
   List<SelectListItem> actionTypesList = new List<SelectListItem>();
   actionTypesList = db.ActionTypes
                    .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID.ToString(),
                                                      Text = s.Name }).ToList();
   return actionTypesList;
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to CreateJobVM

```
@model CreateJobVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.ActionTypeID ,Model.ActionTypes)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.IncidentID,Model.Incidents)
 <input type="submit" />
}
```

When you post the form you can check the property values to get the values user selected in the form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateJobVM model)
{
  //check for model.IncidentID, ActionTypeID
  // to do : Save and redirect
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That's right. Struggling to get my head round this. I'm taking the ID from Incident view to the create page of a Job view. Will this still work? I have a lot of other  fields in the create view, could I not just amend the existing job model?

Comment: Using a lot of ViewBags (which is dynamic) will make your code clumpsy. User Viewmodels to transfer data between your view and action methods. ViewBag/ViewData approach shouldn't be used for this. Add whatever field you have in your view to the viewmodel.

Comment: OK, thanks. The view model is confusing me slightly. I have a generated viewmodel as this was a database first system, :public int JobID { get; set; }
public int IncidentID { get; set; },etc.  cant I just alter this model?

Comment: If you use that, Your UI is tightly coupled to your domain entities. ViewModels are specific for view. They may look similar to your domain entities, but not exactly same.

Comment: Hi working through this now. I am confused slightly with these lines vm.ActionTypes()=GetActionTypesFromSomewhere(); vm.ActionTypes is an non invocable member cannot be used as method? I have tried something like vm.ActionTypes()= new SelectList(db.ActionTypes,"ActionID", "ActionType");

Comment: @user3189899 Sorry It should be simply `vm.ActionTypes`. Updated now. Try that.

Comment: Still having some trouble fitting the parameters into the class on those lines. Also I am not sure where the declaration below the action code fits in.

Comment: Trying something like vm.ActionTypes = db.ActionTypes,"ActionID", "ActionType"; Cannot convert type to <woms.models.actiontype to ***mvc.select list, should it be more like vm.ActionTypes = db.ActionTypes.Select("ActionCode","ActionType1");

Comment: @user3189899 yes you need to convert your custom type to list of select list items.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it with the help of `ViewBag/ViewData`

```
ViewBag.DefaultId=id;

return View();
```

If you have a model based view

```
YourViewModel.DefaultId=id;

return View(YourViewModel);
```

In View,

```
@ViewBag.DefaultId
```

or with ViewModel

```
YourViewModel.DefaultId
```

Comment: So like: ViewBag.IncidentID = id;
            
            return View();   , but then on the create form how does it know the value?

Comment: @user3189899 You can get like `@ViewBag.DefaultId`, edited my answer

Comment: This solution doesn't work if I am writing to the database, right? It just displays the value of IncidentID.