# Populating dropdown from db using mVC 3, linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I can view anybody record and then can edit it if I click edit button below record, after clicking it takes you to another page which shows textboxes and dropdown, checkboxes to edit and all textboxes contains values for that `EmpID` but problem is that I want pre selected value in DROPDOWN LIST, like it should pick corresponding value for each user a preselected like my textboxes.

I am using Linq-to-SQL, ASP.NET MVC 3 and C#

**Code**:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
@model IEnumerable<GetEmployeeEditDetails_SpResult>

@{
    var Item = Model.FirstOrDefault();
 }

<style type="text/css">

</style>
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditEmployee", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <label id="lblName" class="editEmp_label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" value= @Item.EmplName  name="EmpName" placeholder="Update Name" />
  <br />
  <label id="lblDept" class="editEmp_label">Department</label>
  @Html.DropDownList("DeptID", @Item.DeptName)
  <br />
  <label id="lblShift" class="editEmp_label">Shift</label>
  @Html.DropDownList("ShiftId")
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee() 
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Admin"] as string))
    {
        int? EmplId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpEdit"]);
        IEnumerable<GetEmployeeEditDetails_SpResult> EmployeeValues = DataContext.GetEmployeeEditDetails_Sp(EmplId).ToList();
        var DepNames = (from n in DataContext.HrDepts select new { n.DeptID, n.DeptName }).Distinct();
        ViewData["DeptID"] = new SelectList(DepNames, "DeptID", "DeptName");
        var ShiftNames = (from n in DataContext.AtdShifts select new { n.ShiftId, n.ShiftName }).Distinct();
        ViewData["ShiftId"] = new SelectList(ShiftNames, "ShiftId", "ShiftName");
        return View(EmployeeValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017613/how-to-pass-id-to-default-value-of-another-view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a predefined selected value for DropDownList, easiest way is to define the selected value in your SelectList(). So you can simply do this in your controller:

```
ViewData["DeptID"] = 
  new SelectList(DepNames, 
    "DeptID",    // Value
    "DeptName",  // Text
     EmployeeValues.FirstOrDefault().DepId); // selected value
```

Also in your view you need to use @Html.DropDownList like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeptID", (SelectList)ViewData["DeptID"])
```

I would suggest you to read a bit more about the documentation or the hints from intellisense while using html helper classes.

Comment: not working, same result.
new cdoe:
@Html.DropDownList("DeptID", (SelectList)ViewData["DeptID"])
ViewData["DeptID"] = new SelectList(DepNames, "DeptID", "DeptName", EmployeeValues.FirstOrDefault().DeptName);

Comment: What kind of result you are getting? Is the dropdown doesn't have any selection? Or the selection is not defaulted to the one you want?